# Which part of the file system is data, which is programs, which is neither data nor programs

Tags: filesystem

I tried to look for a full list, which shows, what belongs to which category in the file system. So far all articles I found seemed to be not complete. That's, what I have so far:

```
bin  => programs
boot => programs + data?
dev  => neither
etc  => data
home => data
lib  => programs
lost+found => neither/both
misc => ?
mnt  => from current root perspective data
net  => like mnt
opt  => should be programs (and data, if the programming wasn't done well)
proc => neither
sbin => programs
tmp  => data
usr  => seems to be mixed?
var  => mixed also?
```

My problem is especially with `usr` and `var`. Can the subfolders be divided into programs and data? `var` contains `var/lib`, which should be programs. `var/log` on the other hand is definitely data. In `usr`, I expect `usr/bin` to be programs, but `usr/share` to be data.

Comment: Why does it matter? And why the arbitrary distinction between programs and data? And why only on the root level? As a rule of thumb, binaries (programs) will be in: `/bin`, `/opt/bin`, `/sbin` or `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Because I want to cleanly backup all data from my existing system.

Comment: Problem is, the structure is not so clear cut - neither on the root level, or whether you consider "binaries" as programs or data. Instead, you should rather focus on what data you want to backup, and locate that.

Comment: @ArturMeinild That is not the response I hoped for, but the one I expected or at least I'm not surprised.

Comment: You have a good handle on where data *should* be stored. But there is little consequence if a developer ignores those guidelines; there is no Linux Police with enforcement power over everybody. I've seen applications ignore those guidelines and throw data into weird places. @ArturMeinild's guidance to check the *actual* locations of the data you want to preserve is sound and sensible guidance.